# Mongodb Query is slow after indexing for string and Date

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am trying to reduce the query speed in mongodb, not matter how I try to index the query becomes slower after indexing I am not sure, how the indexing should be done, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Screenshot of query Before indexing

[image: Screenshot of query Before indexing]

Screenshot of query After indexing

[image: ScreenShot of query after indexing]